# Factor $y^3-32y+64$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I only remember learning how to factor 2nd degree polynomials, but I don't have a straight method into factoring something like $y^3-32y+64$ into $(y-4)(y^2+4y-16)$.

Would appreciate some help into figuring out a way to do so for general problems like these, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the Rational Root Theorem?

Comment: @Théophile I don't, but I'm guessing I should?

Comment: Yes indeed. :) In short, it's not a coincidence that the root $4$ is a factor of $64$. This gives you a good way to guess what the roots are (if there exist rational roots).

Comment: Already asked and answered at "[How to factor cubic polynomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804234/how-to-factor-cubic-polynomials)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

The possible rational roots of such polynomial belong to the set $\{\pm1,\pm2,\pm4,\pm8,\pm16,\pm32\pm64\}$.

After some few attempts, we find out that $y = 4$ is a root.

Based on such result, we can manipulate such expression as follows
\begin{align*}
y^{3} - 32y + 64 & = (y^{3} - 16y) - (16y - 64)\\\\
& = y(y^{2} - 16) - 16(y-4)\\\\
& = y(y+4)(y-4) - 16(y-4)\\\\
& = [y(y+4) - 16](y-4)\\\\
& = (y^{2} + 4y - 16)(y-4)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Could I do it without figuring out what the rational roots are from the get go? Simplify $y^3-32y+64$ into $y(y^2-16)-16(y-4)$ and figure that $(y-4)$ is the only thing I could factor from both sides, thus get $y(y+4)(y-4)-16(y-4)$ and go from here, or is that not practical?

Comment: Well, you can find out the factor $y - 4$ through inspection, but such approach is not systematic. However it becomes "easier" after doing lots of exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the cubic polynomial $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, start by checking all the integer factors of $d$ divided by the integer factors of $a$. In your case, $a=1$ and $d=64$.. When you do so, $y=4$ will satisfy the polynomial. Once you have one factor, $y-4$, do $(y^3-32y+64)$ divided by $(y-4)$ by long division to get the quadratic factor $y^2+4y-16$. Factor the quadratic to get the other factors, if there are any more rational ones.

Answer (score -6):

I disagree with the approaches stated in the other responses which I have just skimmed.  There is no stipulation that the roots are rational or that the 3rd degree polynomial will bend to normal attempts at factoring.

In my opinion, for a new student, there is only one question:  What is the tried and true method for attacking problems of this type?

Answer: The [Cubic Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation).

**Addendum**
Per trailing comment/request:
Use the Wikipedia article to attack the equation
$y^3 - 32y + 64 = 0.$

The first thing to notice is that the polynomial constitutes a depressed cubic, so the place to start is the "Cardano's formula" section, where 
$p = -32$ and $q = 64$,

Next, following the algorithm, 
$4p^3 + 27q^2 = -114688 < 0$
which indicates that there are three real roots.

At this point, the easiest approach is to then turn to the
"Trigonometric and hyperbolic solutions" section.

Within this section, the first thing to do is to label the  angle $\theta$ as the angle whose cosine is 
$\frac{3q}{2p}\sqrt{\frac{-3}{p}} = 
\frac{192}{-64}\sqrt{\frac{-3}{-32}} = \frac{-3}{4}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}.$

This gives $\theta \approx 156.716283^\circ.$

Taking $\alpha = \theta/3 - (k \times 120^\circ) ~: ~k \in \{0,1,2\}$ 
yields the three **intermediate** values of 
$\cos(52.23875609^\circ) = 0.612372435 = r_1$ 
$\cos(-67.7612439^\circ) = 0.378466979 = r_2$ 
$\cos(-187.761243^\circ) = -0.99083941 = r_3$.

The next step is to double check for math errors
noting that the formula is 
$t = 2\sqrt{\frac{-p}{3}} \times r = 8\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \times r$.

Thus, $t_1 = 8\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \times 0.612372435 = 3.999999995.$
Actually plugging in $t_1 = 4$ confirms that $4$ is a root of the equation, so the rest of the math can be dispensed with, since the equation now routinely factors into a quadratic equation, for the remaining two roots.

At this point, someone fairly new to cubic equations show draw the following conclusions:

1.
While it is unclear, in the depressed cubic, what will happen when $4p^3 + 27q^2 \geq 0$, one of the lessons to be learned when $4p^3 + 27q^2 < 0$ is that apparently, there is no easy way to calculate $\cos(\theta/3)$ when the computation of $\cos(\theta)$ is known. It is probably **not** a good idea to *chase your tail* via the formula 
$\cos(3x) = 4\cos^3(x) - 3\cos(x)$.

2.
You can work with angles in degrees or radians.  Either way, carry all of the decimal places afforded by your calculator.

3.
In general, you probably won't be asked to solve a cubic equation that is not routinely factorable by methods indicated by the other responses.  However, the wikipedia article is the industrial strength approach, when you are having trouble with other approaches.

I emphasize that the OP could routinely have used a calculator, walked down the same path that I did, and then *solved* the cubic using nothing more than wits.

---

In conclusion, it is not a bad idea to learn other methods.  Where I disagree with the other approaches is in priorities.  I would **require** that the algebra student be able to wade through the wikipedia article, following instructions, without drowning.  I see no reason for an algebra student to regard the article as onerous.

It is merely time consuming.

Comment: Would you mind demonstrating?

Comment: Factoring is a good place to start. It's easy to learn, and if the Rational Root Theorem fails, then sure, you can move on to other techniques. But the cubic equation isn't very informative, and it's a lot of work for a beginner.

Comment: Using The-Method-That-Always-Works-But-Is-Complicated from the get-go isn't always the best strategy. Often it's worth to try out The-Method-That-Works-Only-Sometimes-But-Is-Much-Simpler.

Comment: @Théophile You are ignoring that the OP resorted to posting the query.  If the OP had instead worked through the mud of the Wikipedia article, then the query would never have been posted.  Also, although I do favor **meta-cheating** it is pushing it to presume that a teacher/book will not inflict a cubic that is not routinely factorable.  I am not suggesting that the details in the Wikipedia article should be memorized.  However, what I am saying is that in general, if the new student sees no solution after 5 minutes, then slogging through the Wikipedia article should be the **next step**.

Comment: @user2661923 I am not ignoring that. The Rational Root Theorem answers the question almost immediately, and I would absolutely recommend using it before, as you put it, slogging through the mud of the cubic equation.

Comment: @JakeDrone See the just added Addendum to my answer.

Comment: @Théophile I think that we may need to agree to disagree, after you read the just added Addendum to my answer.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I have to say, I'm very curious as to who you're teaching if you expect students to go through such lengths to merely factorize..? I admit going through a wikipedia article for solving your math problems is probably a nice skill set to have, but I wouldn't expect this from a non-math major.

Comment: @JakeDrone It took me a while, because I actually have never waded through the article before, and because I wasn't happy about having to decide to not chase my tail, re calculating $\cos(\theta/3)$ - in fact, that pivotal point is the weak point in my whole approach.  Never the less, if an algebra student can *memorize* the quadratic equation, then they can certainly follow the wikipedia article's instructions, knowing no other math theory.  The general impression that I've gotten is that this is regarded as akin to eating ground glass.  I consider the theory around the cubic as worthwhile.

Comment: @JakeDrone By the way, which is more stringent - learning/memorizing the Rational Root test and recognizing how/when it should be applied, or learning/memorizing *nothing*, and following the Wikipedia article's instructions, with a calculator, step by step?  Remember, that although the OP was (somehow) confronted by the cubic equation, the OP did **not** know (or could not apply) the Rational Root test.

Comment: I am the OP, and for me, it's better to learn and memorize the rational root test simply because it seems simpler and I do not have access to wikipedia articles during university exams ;) PS: I was simply not aware of a rational root test before asking this question.

Comment: @JakeDrone Nice rebuttal.  If you are going to have to solve cubic equations during an in-class exam, then I agree.

Comment: Hold on... you went through a series of calculations only to make an educated guess that there may be a root at $y=4$? And you're against the RRT? While the history behind the cubic equation is of course fascinating, and while there's some merit to being able to follow the steps, it's really not a good place to start for a beginner. I would much rather a student be able to see the factors of $x^3-8$ at a glance than for them to pull out a calculator and starting grinding through inverse cosines.

Comment: @Théophile I am not against the RRT, I am simply against learning/memorizing the RRT vs merely being able to understand (without learning/memorizing) the Wikipedia article.  As Jake Drone rebutted, a clear exception is if you have to confront the cubic during an in-class exam.  Also, re the educated guess, to the best of my knowledge, when $(4p^2 + 27q^3) < 0$ the guess work is clearly better than chasing one's tail via $\cos(3x) = 4\cos^3(x) - 3\cos(x).$ ...see next comment

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the guess work will not be required when $(4p^2 + 27q^3) \geq 0.$  This begs the question, when guess work is required, is it feasible that guess work will **fail** where the RRT will not fail.  Although the stated problem is not an example of such a failure, I do think such failure **is** feasible.  In that event, one may reasonably construe the Wikipedia article as a **failure** for selected cubic equations (vs for example the RRT).  ...see next comment

Comment: @Théophile However, even though such a failure of the Wikipedia article is feasible, this (at least to me) does not mean that priority should be given to learning such theorems as the RRT vs *understanding* selected portions of the Wikipedia article (i.e. creating and then managing a depressed cubic).  As I said before, for all but in-class *exams*, I value understanding the theory around the cubic.